What are the steps to write a book?
I work in a field of mathematics. I have written several survey articles on this area and consider myself a local expert in this field.
As this research area has stabilized, its importance remains. Currently, the technical details are scattered across dozens of papers and held by a few aging experts. I see the need for a comprehensive book that provides a coherent and thorough review of this field. I believe I am well-suited to undertake this project.
I hold a tenured position at a university in the United States, although I am not limited to publishing with a U.S.-based publisher. I plan to spend the next 5-8 years on this project and do not currently foresee the need for a co-author, though that may change later.
What are the best path forward for me to pursue this book project?

If you have something to write about, write it. After you have a draft, approach several publishers. If you are a professional mathematician, you know most of the standard publishers (AMS, EMS, CUP, Springer...).

@MoisheKohan, So a full draft first? Or do you mean a few sample chapters?

It depends: the more you have written, the better are your chances.

@MoisheKohan, I have one sample chapter and one sample section of another chapter. However, this may be a chicken-and-egg problem. Without a book contract, I'm uncertain whether I can secure my department's support for such a long-term project, as we undergo annual evaluations.

I see, then you should start talking to publishers. But in my university, such a contract would mean nothing (I know this from my service on several university promotion committees). Maybe it is different in your place.

@Timmy There are some questions related to what you ask about in the comments: Should a full manuscript be available for a book proposal?, At what point in the writing process should one contact an academic book publisher?

Just for clarification: do you mean a literal, physical book? Because, certainly, if you have a .edu web-page, you can put PDFs (with last-updated data) there making more immediate access possible, as well as making corrections. Yes, that might score even fewer merit-pay-increase points than a physical book, but it might be at least as helpful to students, etc. Also, Cambridge Univ Press, a not-for-profit publisher, offers much more modern/sane copyright and on-line deals for advanced math... maybe not calculus texts... :)

Collecting scattered resuts in one place is a valuable service. For a theoretical math book: don't expect to make much money from royalties.  Even hard-copy academic publishers will nowadays also offer it as an e-book, and probably also offer purchase of individual chapters.

@GEdgar: And for some book series the publisher will not pay any royalties, so you might not receive anything except some free copies of your book.

@paulgarrett, Yes, I do mean a published book, whether an ebook or a physical book. I have draft versions on arXiv that will form the foundation of the book I have in mind. However, I have trouble imagining myself working out all the details, typesetting the pages, checking the spelling, and chasing down all the citations. For now, I still struggle to write just for the joy of writing. I still need some end-goal insight, but perhaps I'll grow out of that one day.

@testaccount which book series? Not paying royalties sounds like a possible characteristic of a predatory publisher, and I'd advise anyone to be very wary of working with such a publisher.

@DanRomik: For example, Springer Lecture Notes in mathematics. I suppose Springer is not considered a predatory publisher. I see that at the end matter of these books the following is written "Authors receive a total of 30 free copies of their volume and free access to their book on SpringerLink, but no royalties. They are entitled to a discount of 33.3 % on the price of Springer books purchased for their personal use, if ordering directly from Springer."

@testaccount interesting, thanks. Yes, Springer are respectable and I wouldn't consider them predatory.

There are a couple of ways to publish a book: with a publisher or self publishing. I've done both and have about 15 books behind me. Generally in CS (most) and math.
With a publisher:
To publish with a publisher you need to make contact with an "acquisitions editor" who drives the process of evaluating and selecting books. You can do this at any stage of the creation of a book. Prior to writing anything substantial, you just make a proposal, a "pitch" for the need for such a book. An outline or TOC would help. If you have written part of it that might give some credibility and gives the editor a better chance to make a decision that the publisher will be happy with. Or, you can have the complete book, or, what the editor will consider a draft.
Expect the editor to have your proposal (or the book) reviewed by someone they trust who is familiar with the area and who can give them an idea of potential sales. Expect that the book will need revision, perhaps several revisions before it is finally published. I've gotten inconsistent reviews on at least one of my books and had to work that out with the publisher.
Expect that the publisher will only expend marketing effort on the published book for a few years (2-3 maybe) unless it is wildly successful. Don't expect to make a lot of money from a book (unless, unlike almost all books, it is wildly successful).
A good place to meet an acquisitions editor is at a conference attended by educators in your field, where book sellers have displays of their works. Such an editor frequently attends such meets and is anxious to meet people and listen to suggestions. If you are already well-known, and have a history of publishing, such editors might seek you out at meetings or otherwise. I've both pitched books and had ideas pitched to me by editors.
Read any offers to publish carefully. Be aware, especially, about financial consequences if a book is not successful. Not all publishers like to take financial responsibly for their poor decisions.
If a book is successful, expect pressure to produce a new edition every other year. If you refuse, the publisher might be able to replace you as author of future editions. Read the contract. They probably hold copyright.
Self Publishing:
To self publish, you just write the book and then use something like Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP, an Amazon company) to produce and sell the book. This is only likely to work if you are already well-known to most of the people interested in your ideas in book form; other university faculty. If you have a presence in the field this can work. But marketing is then strictly up to you. And you lose the advantage of copy editors and graphics designers that a formal publisher can provide. You also have to absorb the cost of obtaining an ISBN for the work. Co-authors can spread the work and also provide some copy editing and such. I find that it is very difficult to copy edit my own work.
The copyright remains with you. KDP is just a manufacturer/seller, though they have some rules about what is allowed.
General:
I never got any "support" from my university for any books. The books enhanced my reputation among educators and my dean(s) liked the fact that I was well known, but the books were all "works of love". This is especially true of one math book I wrote to honor an old, deceased, mentor. Some others were to extend the work of colleagues (and co-authors).
Almost all of my books are intended for novices. There is a wider market for such books than for advanced material in math and CS. If you want to write a book, do it because it will be meaningful to you and as a service to the profession. I've sold a lot of copies over the years, but not enough to meaningfully improve my lifestyle. Some have sold almost no copies. I have known at least one millionaire author of a math book, though he too got his satisfaction from teaching. I haven't had any sales in years from the books produced by recognized publishers.

absorb the cost of obtaining an ISBN for the work - Amazon (probably some other self-publishing platforms) basically provides the ISBN for free.

If you write an advanced math book, almost all the sales will come soon after publishing when a lot of university libraries buy a copy. Once every major library has a copy sales are essentially done.

Nice answer.  When dealing with a publisher, do you handle the details and make the connections yourself, or do you recommend finding representation for that?  If looking for a literary agent for an academic work, what do you recommend having in hand?  A TOC and a chapter or two??

@ScottSeidman, I've never used an intermediary. The publisher's people are helpful in my experience. I gave up with the big outfits and moved to self publishing due to the quick drop off in marketing effort. But, for academic publishing, I doubt that there is a lot of room to bargain. We aren't in the millions of copies sort of market that some established novelists are. With few exceptions. In CS we have a lot of large meetings that the publishers show up at and it is pretty easy to make contact. Yes, a bit of prior work, TOC etc can be helpful if it is your pitch. Not needed if you're known.

At what stage or stages will some kind of peer review take place? Or at all?

There might be an initial review of the concept. But you might get constant oversight once you have a complete draft until publication. It depends on the editor and their comfort with you and the project. Books are a bigger project than papers with more to gain/lose. An experienced author probably has less oversight. A copy editor might go through more than one cycle with an author. My first book had a lot of oversight. Less as I became known.

I'm an author of 3 books. I think you hold some misconceptions (which seem to be fairly common in my experience among would-be first time authors) about the process of publishing a math book. Once those are cleared up, the process will appear much simpler than you make it out to be, and the path forward should be clear.
Misconception 1: there are "steps" to writing a book.
There aren't. There's only one step, which is to write the book. (Even if you mean "steps to publishing" rather than "steps to writing", the step of writing the book is the only nontrivial one, and the only one you should devote any serious attention to before you have written, say, 75% of the actual book.)
Misconception 2: you have a good ability to predict your level of desire to be working on a book 5-8 years into the future.
You don't. Most people who start books never finish them - they get tired and lose interest and motivation after a much shorter amount of time than 5-8 years. (And I'd bet most of them aren't even planning projects that they initially believe will take that long.)
Misconception 3: you have a good ability to predict how long it will take you to finish your book (even assuming your prediction that you will finish it is correct).
You don't. See this anecdote from Daniel Kahneman's wonderful book Thinking, Fast and Slow.
Misconception 4: publishers are so patient they will consider offering an author a book contract to publish a book that will be finished in 5 years.
That seems vanishingly unlikely based on my experience and my general knowledge about how the academic publishing industry works. A publisher will give you a 1-year deadline to finish your book; maybe 2 years if you're lucky and they really like your idea.
Misconception 5: math departments are so supportive they will offer you some special leeway in your annual evaluations because you have a book contract and say you will be finishing a book in 5-8 years.
Again, I think that's highly doubtful. As someone else said, you have tenure so it's not even clear why you need the department's support. But to the extent that you do need support, I think the most likely (and correct) thing for your department to do would be to evaluate you based on your actual, measurable productivity, not based on your self-attested status of writing a book, even if supported by the existence of a book contract. (Again, math departments are probably just as aware as book publishers that many people who start writing a book won't finish it.)
Now, to be clear, measurable productivity could include actual book chapters that you've written and are willing to show your colleagues. Even if the chapters are part of an unpublished draft manuscript, they may still carry some weight in your evaluation. The point that I'm making here is that such material represents evidence of actual work. A book contract, by contrast, represents evidence of essentially nothing.
Discussion
Here are the conclusions that I would draw about your plan from the above discussion. Until you have written several books and can reliably predict your writing output and consistency based on that experience, I'd suggest planning a first book that would take a much shorter amount of time than what you're suggesting here. E.g., plan for a book you think will take you 1-2 years to finish. Even with such a relatively modest plan, you are statistically somewhat likely to lose steam and give up before finishing. And even if you do end up finishing, you are statistically almost certain to take quite a bit longer to finish than your initial plan calls for.
The writing should be the focus of your attention for the main duration of the project. As I said, there are no "steps", only writing.
Some people might suggest to try to find a publisher early on in the writing process. I have never believed this to be good advice. To me, the desire to get a book contract early on comes from a feeling of insecurity that some authors have about whether their book idea is actually good, and the wish for the validation that comes from a publisher signing on to the project. Well, maybe the insecurity is justified in some cases - I assume some book projects are genuinely not that impressive - but if you really have those kinds of doubts about your own idea, then I'd say you're pretty unlikely to finish your book anyway, with or without a book contract. In fact, the added pressure of a book contract and a deadline might well end up making you more likely to fail, not less. So get your validation and alleviate your doubt in other ways, for example by showing early drafts to your colleagues and getting confirmation from them that you're on a promising path.
If you think a book contract will be good to have lined up early on as a way of impressing your department and getting them to take your plans seriously, as I said I think that's misguided and that having a contract won't have the effect you are expecting. So that at least is not a good reason to approach publishers early IMO.
Instead, if you want to be taken seriously by your department, then just write. (If you make draft chapters publicly available online while the book is in progress, you will be taken doubly seriously, as your colleagues both inside and outside the department will be able to see what you are doing, and your work can start getting used by others even before the book is finished. I speak from experience here - my first book took 4-5 years to write and my department was indeed pretty impressed by seeing my partial progress and some of the impact it was making.)
Finally: don't get the wrong impression here that I think your plan to write a book is a bad idea. On the contrary, it sounds like a great and commendable plan, and your description of the motivation that's driving you to do it sounds like exactly the right sort of motivation for doing a project like this (and similar to the motivation I had). I only think you are thinking too ambitiously in terms of the scope of the project. Seriously, 5-8 years is just too long. It might actually end up taking you that long if you plan for 2-3 years, and I shudder to think how long your 5-8 year planned book will take to write...
Anyway, best of luck!

As a well-known and extreme case-in-point: Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming...

@AlexanderWoo I think we just need to discard TAOCP as a really bizarre outlier. It's the only case I can think of where I own a third edition copy of a book that hasn't been written yet.  (Well, TAOCP and "A Time-Traveller's Guide to the 21th Century", but that's also a special case.)

@AlexanderWoo yes, George R. R. Martin’s Song of Ice and Fire “trilogy” is another example in this category of bizarre authorial mission creep. And Martin was already an experienced author when he started work on his planned 3-book series.

@DanRomik, Okay, I got perfect score in this misconception quiz. About point #4 though, 1~2 years sounds really short. So does it mean you need a nearly finished manuscript before proposing a book?

@Timmy - The answer proposes a 75% finished manuscript.  The point where the project stops resembling a book idea and starts resembling a book draft with a still slightly unfinished structure and a few remaining missing chapters.

@JirkaHanika, I imagine just the final revision process alone will take more 1 year or more.

@Timmy you can propose a book to a publisher at any point. As I said, my own view is that it serves little purpose to propose it at an early stage of the project, and can even be counterproductive. But there is no rule that says you can't do it (and no rule that says that my advice on such things is always right).

Just sit down and do the following two steps.

Write down what your book should cover, like the table of contents.
Write one chapter.

Do those steps just for you, do not talk to anybody that you started writing a book. Once you finish writing a single chapter, you can estimate how big the task will be, how much writing in solitude annoys you, how much it energizes you, and how competing tasks are suffering.
Now is the right time to consider:

Do you still want to write the book? Are other things like teaching, supervising students, writing papers, giving talks more awarding to you?
Should you involve co-authors? Would this help you with your working routine?
Do you need to structure your thoughts and give you confidence by reaching out to a publisher?

I would wait with any form of too early commitment like signing a contract that might pressure you and lead to a feeling of a having a failed book project.

I have several suggestions.
Your tenure frees you to follow whatever scholarship path you choose. You don't need your department's approval, though years with a growing draft instead of published papers may cost you some merit raise points.
You don't need a contract to get started, even to finish.
I have written several books, each of which began as class notes. Over the years it took to turn those notes into a book I used drafts as the text. Since you are writing a monograph on a special area this might not work for you from year to year, but you might be able to offer a graduate class now and then.
While you write you can contact publishers informally - parhaps at meetings.
Build a work flow that allows you to compile an up to date draft easily. Presumably you will use LaTeX.  Structure your document with a common preamble, chapters in separate folders, Index and cross reference and maintain literature citations as you go.
Post your latest draft on your web site.

Yes, it does bear repeating that, in principle, having tenure should mean that you've proven yourself, so that your choices for your activities are a-priori good. You've passed the gate. Pleasing other people and conforming to their expectations is no longer the most-essential thing to think about on a daily basis. Yes, it is hard to recover from that thinking after 10 years working toward tenure... :)

Yes, tenure provides me with a certain degree of freedom. However, is such extensive freedom potentially problematic? Perhaps a book contract could offer some external motivation to help me navigate this lengthy process. Or is it wishful thinking?

Without the desire to write a book it will become hard to finish it.

@Timmy https://www.ted.com/talks/derek_sivers_keep_your_goals_to_yourself

Expanding on the "work with a publisher" section of Buffy's answer, to which I have direct experience with on the other side:
Go to your preferred publisher's website and submit a publication proposal. Example for Springer. For this publisher you can also contact one of their Publishing Editors (here's the page for the ones in mathematics). Springer also has a guide for what to put in the publication proposal. You'll need to provide a scope for the book, its estimated length, its intended market, etc. The good news here is that publishers are always looking for new projects, so they'll likely be happy to talk.
The publishing editor will then guide you on the next steps. Odds are, the publication proposal will be peer reviewed, which might result in suggested changes to the scope and such. If the project is approved, they'll send you a contract, which you should look at carefully before signing. From there, you write the book, submit it when complete, and the publisher will handle the bulk of the production process. Your input will be required for a few things, such as the book cover or blurb or intended readership in the marketing materials.
One part of Buffy's answer that does not match my experience is that there're no financial consequences for you if the book sells poorly. The publisher assumes that risk. But you'll almost surely receive less royalties in this case (royalties are generally based on the sales revenue).
One more thing: if you're at a large university then the university might have a university press (example for MIT) with an office on campus. You could visit them and ask them about the process, or publish with them if you choose.

Writing a book for royalties will lead to nowhere.

A friend of mine suffered greatly on her successful second book because her first book sold poorly after she received an advance. The major publisher withheld royalties for the second book. I hope it doesn't happen often, but it can happen. Read the contract. BTW, there was nothing "wrong" about the first book. The publisher just vastly overestimated the market. I won't name the publisher but all here would recognize it.

@Allure, Since you have experience from the publisher side, may I sneak this bonus question in: What are the usual consequences of not deliver a book on time or at all?

@Timmy nothing. The due date gets moved, and everyone moves on to the next project.

@Buffy Well she did get an advance in that case - although even then, she could approach another publisher ...
